# String Splitup and assign to array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, split

Two space separated values that corresponds to price and quantity of each item. Input is provided as String based on N (count of line items)

120.98 7

151.99 8

141.39 4

137.71 7

121.27 6

187.29 11

How to store in array the price and quantity separately and print the same.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: seems like a homework

Answer (score 0):

You can use StringTokenizer to separate the tokens

```
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
String input=sc.nextLine();
StringTokenizer st=new StringTokenizer(input);
double price=Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken());
int qty=Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
```

now you can store `price` and `qty` in array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split()` method to splitUp the string.

```
public class MainClass{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        List<Double> priceList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Integer> qtyList = new ArrayList<>();
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        String input=sc.nextLine();
        if(input != null) {
            String[] arr = input.split("  ");
            priceList.add(Double.parseDouble(arr[0]));
            qtyList.add(Integer.parseInt(arr[1]));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**The simple approach to store and print would be as follows.**

Simply create two string arrays. One for storing the price and another one for Storing the quantity. After reading each line of input from user, use split function for splitting the string. The complete code is below:

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class TestArr {
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
{
DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(System.in);
int N=0;
String price[] = new String[100];
String quantity[] = new String[100];
//To get the value for N
N = Integer.parseInt(din.readLine());

//To get each line item and store the values
for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
{
    String str = din.readLine();
    price[i] = str.split(" ")[0];
    quantity[i] = str.split(" ")[1];
}

//To display the price and quantity
for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
System.out.println("Price: "+price[i]+" Quantity: "+quantity[i]);

}
}
```

**The professional approach would be as follows.**

Create a class for the item with two variables. One is for storing Price and one is for storing quantity. And use that Item class in an ArrayList. Complete code is below:

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

//Item class for storing each item
class Item
{
float price;
int quantity;
public Item(float price, int quantity)
{
    this.price = price;
    this.quantity = quantity;
}
}

//Main Class
public class TestArr {
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
{
//Input stream to read inputs from user
DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(System.in);

//To store count of line items
int N=0;
//Arraylist to store each of the line items
ArrayList<Item> arr = new ArrayList<Item>();
System.out.println("Enter count of Line Items:");
N = Integer.parseInt(din.readLine());
for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
{
    String st = din.readLine();
    Item item = new Item(Float.parseFloat(st.split(" ")[0]),                
Integer.parseInt(st.split(" ")[1]));
}
//To print the line items
for(Item item : arr)
{
    System.out.println("Price: "+item.price+" Quantity: "+item.quantity);
}

}
}
```